# Проблема в сортировке шелла

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Задание в универе сделать сортировку шелла.
Вроде сортирует, а вроде и нет. Не могу найти ошибку.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void BucketSort(){
}

int main()
{
    const int size = 30;
    int mass[size];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        mass[i] = rand()% 30;
        cout << mass[i] << " ";
    }
    int D = size / 2;
    for (int j =0; j < size+D; j++){
        for (int i = 0; i < size-D; i++) {
            if (mass[i] < mass[i + D]) {
                int temp = mass[i + D];
                mass[i + D] = mass[i];
                mass[i] = temp;
            }
        }
        D = D / 2;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Result" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << mass[i] << " ";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: скриншот]

Comment: в условии цикла не  j < size+D;, а  j <  D;

Comment: Все равно сортирует не правильно

Comment: погуглите, думаю примеров сортировки будет много...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Это НЕ сортировка Шелла. Та использует вставки для сортировки подсерий, а здесь пузырёк, как в сортировке расчёской (CombSort)

2) К тому, что заметил @AR Hovsepyan  `for (int j = 0; j < D...`, следует добавить, что `j` никак не используется, и вообще цикл по `j` не нужен

3) На страницe wiki Наиболее близок к приведенному [вариант на Java](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9#%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B0_Java), из него можно сделать C++:

```
int swapped = 1;
int D = size;
while (swapped){
    swapped = 0;
    int half = D / 2;
    D = half?half:1;
    for (int i = 0; i < size-D; i++) {
        if (mass[i] < mass[i + D]) {
            int temp = mass[i + D];
            mass[i + D] = mass[i];
            mass[i] = temp;
            swapped = 1;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Я уже не помню как у Шелла сортировка, но помню, что перебор начинается с середины массива,  и  написал первое, что заметил

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan Не совсем с середины - например, на первом шаге взяли индексы 0,3,6 и отсортировали этот набор вставками. Потом индексы 1,4,7 и так далее.